# Trigger Jquery event from ASP.NET server-side code?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a simple JQuery enabled ASP.NET page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });
  </script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3><a id="Accordion1" href="#">Accordion Panel 1</a></h3>
            <div>
                A form input...
                <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
            <h3><a id="Accordion2" href="#">Accordion Panel 2</a></h3>
            <div>
            Some content...
            </div>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you'll notice, I'm using an UpdatePanel also.

btnSubmit_Click event does something like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some MySql INSERT, etc.
}
```

Now what I want to do is for server-side **btnSubmit_Click** to trigger JQuery to "click" Accordion Panel 2 (so it will open Accordion Panel 2 and close 1). How to do this?

UPDATE: Sorry guys I forgot to mention earlier that It's got an UpdatePanel

Comment: Can I put something in "OnClientClick" of the server-side button, then fire up something from my .js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, I just used the "change the value of a hiddenfield after postback then let jquery read that hiddenfield" approach. Thanks guys!

Jquery:

```
var tag = $("#contentBody_hfTag1").val();
if (tag=="1") { $(".Accordion").accordion({ active: 1 }); }
else { $(".Accordion").accordion({ active: 0 }); }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfTag1" ClientIDMode="Predictable" Value="0" runat="server" />
```

C#

```
protected void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hfTag1.Value = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Jquery runs on the client, your handler is on the server.  You will need to trigger the event on the client when the page reloads after the post back.

Comment: thanks. i just changed the value of a server-side hiddenfield that jquery will read after postback. seems to work ok. not neat but works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as Jquery works on client side, from a  server side event, as the page reloads. And the state of the accordion will be lost. So what you can do is, instead of making a post back, you can do the same work in a Jquery AJAX call on the button click to do whatever you want and then close the accordion 1 and show accordion 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <i88:InlineScript runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('Accordion2').click()
            </script>
        </i88:InlineScript>
        <asp:Button ID="cmd" runat="server" Text="Update" />        
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You can put inlineScript which will get Executed every time you update the Panel.
You can also use [jQuery.Trigger();](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for other event's.

Comment: Thanks, but may I ask where did <i88:InlineScript> come from?

Comment: @A.B.User is jut an example token from Google ,you can replace i88 with you're need's.